# Shared synchronized pool in JBoss 7 cluster

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, cluster-computing

**Background**

I have a clustered JBoss environment with two nodes. I have successfully implemented two clustered scheduled tasks that only run on one node at a time. If the node that currently owns the scheduled task is shut down, ownership is transfered to the other node. I used the official example [here](http://www.jboss.org/jdf/quickstarts/jboss-as-quickstart/cluster-ha-singleton/) to achieve it, and it works like a charm.

**What I want do do**

*Note that below is not about schedules. It is about a Singleton that now needs to keep state over the cluster. Above is just a description of what I have tried.*

Now I have a connection pool that needs to be distributed over the nodes as well. This pool contains a synchronized list containing abstractions of connections to an external system. A client "borrows" a connection, does some job, and returns it. This happens quite frequently, at most 6000 times per hour. It is defined as a `@Singleton` EJB, simplified it looks something like this:

```java
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ConnectionPoolBean {

    private SomeObjectWithSynchronizedPool pool;

    public void borrowConnection() {
        pool.getConnectionFromSynchronizedList();
    }

    public void returnConnection() {
        pool.returnConnectionFromSynchronizedList();
    }

}
```

And I want to access the class like below if possible (it is legacy code which I can modify). `connectionPool` would then refer to the same object, regardless of which node is executing the code.

```java
@Stateless
public class SomeBeanUsingPool implements SomeBeanUsingPoolInterface {

    @EJB
    private ConnectionPoolBean connectionPool;

    public void doSomething() {
        connectionPool.borrowConnection();
        // do stuff...
        connectionPool.returnConnection();
    }

}
```

**What I have tried**

I reused the implementation described in *background*, implementing a HA Singleton Service. That meant, however, that the class was only available at one node at a time (i.e. for node 2 it isn't started in the container until node 1 goes down). This made me realize that a clustered HA Singleton is not the way to go here, it only makes sure the bean is only available at one node at a time.

**Question**

How can I achieve my goal, **having a shared pool for the whole cluster**? What I really need to share is the `ConnectionPoolBean.pool` object, since it's there that the synchronization happens. Although it would be nice to share the whole `ConnectionPoolBean` across the cluster. Also, I need to keep state if one node goes down, which I don't think a HA Singleton is suitable for.

Comment: Is it an active/active or active/passive cluster? Do you have a database in your cluster?

Comment: I'll try to answer your question as good as I can (I am no clustering expert, yet :). Both nodes are identical and run simultaneously, I guess that makes it active/active. Both nodes use the same db. We use Hibernate and JBoss full profile. Which means (if I've got it right, which the JConsole seems to verify) that infinispan caches entities out of the box in the cluster. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Maybe I have not understood your requirements correctly, but what about having normal pools on each node, and synchronize on something else (a semaphore table in database for example). Shared state could be in a database as well. The question is a little bit abstract. What does your pool contain? What's the connection pool *queue*? What is the frequency of your tasks?

Comment: *queue* was a typo of me. I tried to make the question as clear as I could, but I see what you mean. The pool is an abstraction of free connections to an external system. A node "borrows" a connection from the pool, talks to the external system, and returns the connection. Frequency doing this would top at around 6000 calls per hour. I would like to avoid your database solution if possible. A database solution would work, but that requires some overhead. I would hope that there exist some elegant JEE/JBoss way to solve this.

Comment: I have read scheduled tasks ("jobs"), so I haven't expected that frequency. So yes, I agree, the database solution is probably not suitable. But what is the object you synchronize on (concurrent number of users)? What about [shared state](http://initbinder.com/articles/jboss_clustering_shared_state_across_cluster_partition.html)?

Comment: I tried to clarify my question a bit. Anyway, a shared state is more or less what I'm trying to acheive. Thanks for the link. It is from 2008, so might not be appicable to JBoss7 but thanks anyway.